# Как задать бесконечный вызов функции через setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, массивы, слайдер

у меня есть функции для работы с простеньким слайдером, хочу сделать чтобы он бесконечно перематывался, через setTimeout, но как это реализовать, не знаю. Помогите пожалуйста, кому не сложно. p.s не судите за код. Только учусь.

```
   function next(){
        var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
        num++;
        if(num >= image.length){
            num = 0;
        }
        slider.src=image[num];
    }
    function prev(){
        var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
        num--;
        if(num < 0){
            num= image.length-1;
        }
        slider.src=image[num];
    }
    
    setTimeout('next()',2000);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function autoNext() {
  next();
  setTimeout(autoNext, 2000); 
}
setTimeout(autoNext, 2000);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но немного не могу понять как это работает.  Есть функция которая внутри себя вызывает 2 функции, себя и next(), а после выполнения она опять же выполняет себя? И всё по кругу? Я ведь правильно понял?

Comment: @HLEBHLEB Не "вызывает ... себя", а заказывает вызов себя через две секунды.